# Capitalizing family members' names (i.e. nouns, NOT proper nouns)

Tags: proper-nouns, capitalization, kinship-terms

My daughter's English text book has a note which reads if you are ***directly*** talking to a person ***about*** the only person in your house, it can be capitalized.

For example:

> *"Mommy, have you seen my tab?"* 
>  *"What would I do with it? Ask your **Sister**. She's fond of playing on it"*

I want to confirm the capitalization of 'sister' here. This is *new* to me, actually!

And yes, it has *nothing* to do with emphasizing 'sister' that many *may* think the reason of capitalizing. Say--

> *"Yes, last night I asked Mommy about it, but then she gave a reluctant smile!"*

Comment: That's a new one on me. The only time I've seen Sister capitalised like that was when the book in question features nuns. Also, what's a tab? At least in Australia, saying somebody has 'a tab' means they have a tablet - usually of Ecstasy. Sister probably should avoid playing on that. :P

Comment: Hey, is in AuE 'new on me' common? I think, it's either 'new to me' or 'for me'. And, in India, tab stands for a tablet computer.

Comment: @RuchirM "That's/it's a new one on me" is fairly common down here, yes.

Comment: @DamienH a tab is generally a tablet, with a touchpad etc... like a big smartphone but which can't phone... :)

Comment: some tabs *do* have phone facility though .. ) @Random

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227200/is-mum-mam-mom-etc-ever-capitalised

Comment: @JamesWebster thanks James. However, I found a good reference on this. Answered my own question.

Comment: Just came across this question and remembered my similar question. Your answer here is actually better than the answer on mine as it has a reference! Do you want to answer on ELU?

Comment: Done @JamesWebster I think it is helpful there as well. :) thanks for drawing my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book 'Painless Grammar' by Rebecca, PhD

Capitalize 'mom' and 'dad' when you are calling your parent's name **but** not when you refer to 'my mom' and 'my dad'.

**CAPS**

> Hi Mom! Welcome home, Dad

**NO CAPS**

> My father and my mother are busy. Could your mom or dad drive us to the movie?

Answer (score 10):

Your daughter's textbook is not quite accurate.

You capitalize such nouns when they act as names, as the ordinary form of address. "Mommy" is used that way in your second example.

But in your first example, *sister* is not a name, as its use with a determiner makes clear: it is a common noun denoting a relationship.

If the determiner is omitted, however, the noun is treated as a name, and it is proper to capitalize:

> Ask Sister. She's fond of playing on it.

That sort of use of *sister* is rare, although not unknown; as Damien H says,  *Sister*, capitalized, is usually the title (of reference and address) for a Catholic nun.

Comment: the sentence is *not* from the textbook...as I don't remember the exact exercise under the chapter, I just made my own sentence. But what I am curious about is 'noun' of family members taking 'capital'. So, looking at this answer, it seems correct.

Comment: And occasionally "Sister", used as a name, gets turned into a nickname, usually "Sissy". (It's still capitalized that way, as you'd expect.)