# Is the word Mom here considered as that person's mom or is a person called mom?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, vocative

Is the word Mom here considered as that person's mom or is a person called mom?

> Just wait until Mom sees this!

Comment: Usually, "Mom" is short for "**my** Mom" (occasionally, "**your** Mom"), where "Mom" is a diminutive derived from / meaning ***mother***. But exactly what's going on in the mind of the speaker (who will often just be a child who's still *learning* how to use English) is usually ***a matter of opinion***. Not many people are actually *called* "Mom", but obviously this will happen sometimes.

Comment: So which one is it here? my mom or your mom or our mom or is just a person with the name "mom?

Comment: Technically, it's ambiguous.  Mom could be someone's name (I've never heard of anyone with that name, but it could be a foreign name, or a name someone has made up - albeit a very strange one to make up).  However, in reality, in 99.9999% of cases, "Mom" means "mother".  The capital letter certainly doesn't indicate otherwise; it's usual to capitalise "Mom" when it means "my mother".

Comment: I don't have a clue! You wrote the words, but you haven't given enough context. All I can say is it's ***more likely*** to be a kid referring to his own mother (he may or may not be talking to a sibling). I'd have thought ***all*** languages would have this potential ambiguity around words for "mother" and "father".

Comment: @rjpond but that mom's name isn't Mom so why do we capitalize it?

Comment: See [Capitalizing family members' names (i.e. nouns, NOT proper nouns).](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63704/capitalizing-family-members-names-i-e-nouns-not-proper-nouns) Usually we *wouldn't* capitalise if preceded by a possessive: *Just wait until **my mom** sees this!*

Comment: But why is it capitalized? isn't capitalization for proper nouns and proper nouns are someone's name which in this case the mother doesn't have the name "Mom"

Comment: @pobig43001  Long-standing convention.  Nicknames are usually capitalised too, even ones that aren't abbreviations of the person's original name.

Comment: so in this case "Mom" is a nickname for their mother? also what does Long-standing mean here?

Comment: Because if "Mom" ***is*** preceded by a determiner (usually, a "possessive", such as ***my** mom, **your** dad*), even the "diminutive"  form is just a "generic" reference indicating the nature of the familial relationship. It's only normally seen as a proper noun / name if there's no determiner. But it all depends on who is talking to who - and as the existing answer here indicates, at least *some* people think that if the speaker chooses not to include a possessive *(**my**)*, that must be because he's talking to another family member who shares the relationship *(**our** mom)*.

Comment: The rules of capitalisation go beyond proper nouns (for instance, the pronoun "I" is always capitalised).  They also vary from language to language (English capitalises days of the week but not seasons; some languages capitalise neither; some languages don't capitalise the word for "I" but do capitalise the word for "you", at least in formal letters) .  "Mom" is used as though it were someone's name, so it follows the same rules as other names.  (If it were preceded by "my" or "your" then it would be lower case.)

Comment: The fact someone downvoted my answer is ridiculous. This is just not that difficult and I believe we may be in the presence of a troll and I'm wondering when the others are going to catch on. Or, as the Brits say: taking the piss.

Comment: @rjpond I think you are being pulled in, "My Mom told me so".

Comment: @Lambie Right.  I would prefer to use lower case there, but capitalisation is a legitimate choice.

Comment: At https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mom the examples for "her mom" and "my mom" are not capitalised.  But @pobig43001 you'll see that it also says "--often used as a name", followed by a capitalised example: "Have you asked Mom if we can go?"

Comment: what if mom in "her mom" was a proper noun like it is the person's name so it should be capitalized in that case?

Comment: @rjpond See what I mean about taking the piss? Now, we're into repetition.

Comment: @pobig43001 "Mom" isn't a proper noun, but it is often used as though it were (in sentences like "I told Mom") and thus capitalised.  Where it is used like any other common noun (as in "her mom"), I would put it in lower case.

Comment: How do we know that "Mom" isn't a proper noun?

Comment: Would you please stop now? All your issues have been addressed. Writers capitalize what they want to capitalize and in **dialogues it can function like a proper noun**. Please do not ask this question again.

Answer (score 2):

"Just wait until Mom sees this!" [American English]
"Just wait until Mum sees this!" [British English]
"Just wait until Mother sees this!" [formal, either English]

**That means the speaker is addressing someone (a brother or sister) and saying their mother will be angry when she sees whatever the thing or situation is.**

Mom in American English is mother. And here, it means: **our** mother. But the pronoun our is not needed in verbal exchanges between siblings, or kids talking about their mother to a family member. If they were talking to someone **outside the family**, the boy or girl would probably say: my or our mom or mum or mother.

There is no doubt about the meaning and actually does not require more context.

Comment: But why is it capitalized? isn't capitalization for proper nouns and proper nouns are someone's name which in this case the mother doesn't have the name "Mom"

Comment: Because it's in a dialogue and it functions **like a proper name**.

Comment: what do you mean by a dialogue? and proper name is someone's name so the mother most likely doesn't have this name

Comment: A dialogue is a conversation between two people. Let me ask you something: If you talk to your brother or sister, do you use your mother's name?? I doubt it. But your mother has a name, right? Think  in your own language. It is most likely exactly the same thing....

Comment: In BrE, at least, "wait until Mum sees that" does not necessarily imply that the speaker and addressee share a mother.  But that's a minor quibble - I'll upvote.