# Names of family members and articles

Tags: articles

When do we use articles with names of family members? Is it right that for example when I inform someone about my siblings I could say...

> *I have a sister*

Is it also possible to treat this word "sister" as a ***proper name***, and say...

> *Sister is there*
> *Come here, sister*

Comment: Using *brother* or *sister* as a proper noun for your sibling is *very* unusual in most families. Note that reported speech in books, and *actual* speech in movies, TV soap operas, etc. will often overuse this feature as a  "narrative device" to inform and remind the reader / audience of context-relevant family relationships, giving a misleading impression of how people in the real world normally interact. Some people use diminutive ***bro*** or ***sis*** with that *literal* sense - but lots of people use those forms freely for just about *anyone* they interact with, so you never really know.

Comment: ...but nobody *ever* says things like *Sister is in the other room* ("third person" reference). We're talking about directly addressing your sibling with something like *Good morning Sis[ter]! Do you want a cup of coffee?* ("second person" reference)

Comment: The question is about articles and family member names, but then the example (*Sister is here.*) does not use any article. Do you expect the sentence to be *The Sister is here.* (or *The sister is here.*)?

Comment: Some punctuation might help.

Comment: @apaderno: The OP seems to be asking whether s/he can say *Sister is here* the same as ***Jane** is here.* Answer: No (and no-one ever says ***The Jane** is here*, either).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is what I understood too, but what's the matter about articles? (*When do we use articles with names of family members?*) It seems the question is "merging" two different topics.

Comment: (I keep forgetting that on a comment thread where just another person commented, my comment notifies that person too. My first comment was for the OP.)

Comment: @apaderno: The punctuation isn't great, but the question quite clearly asks whether it is *possible to treat this word "sister" as a **proper name** and say "Sister is here".* I don't see any need for further clarification.

Comment: Related (but probably *not* a duplicate) [Is the word Mom here considered as that person's mom or is a person called mom?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/277931/is-the-word-mom-here-considered-as-that-persons-mom-or-is-a-person-called-mom)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question explicitly asks *When do we use articles with names of family members?* It cannot then use a totally different example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - people say 'the Donald', though, don't they?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That was pointed out recently (either here or on ELU). I recall attempting without success to think of similar examples. For all I know, Trump himself deliberately created and/or encouraged the usage, because it's *exactly* the kind of thing that wouldn't bother his supporters (it even adds a kind of "cachet"). But it would send his enemies into paroxysms of rage about the mistreatment of the English language! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The US comedy TV series _Seinfeld_ had, I gather, a 1995 episode called 'The Jimmy' featuring a thus-named character who continually refers to himself in the third person.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I don't know if Trump himself ever uses/used "The Donald". Come to that, I don't know if ["The Fonz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonzie) referred to himself by either that two-word handle OR "Fonzie". All I remember for sure is *other* characters said things like *Let's ask Fonzie*, but I don't know if they ever said *We need the Fonz to help us here* (maybe that was only in the show title).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - when I was in the Civil Service we referred to a particularly pompous senior manager as 'the Johnson' which was both his name, and, if you get my drift, his nature.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common to use "mother" and "father" (or "mum" and "dad") in place of names. When using these words in place of names, no article is used, but a different determiner is possible, such as "my":

> I gave my mother a present.

> Mum woke me up this morning.

But nothing at all when used as a "vocative":

> Mum!  Where's my football shirt?

It is much rarer, to use other family words as a vocative.  So don't say:

> ?Sister woke me up this morning.

> ?Sister! where are you?

This may be because English doesn't have a way of specifying which sister this refers to, nor even a way to distinguish between an elder and younger sister.

"A sister" is quite unusual, outside of expressions like "I have a sister", because normally you would be speaking about a determined person, and so say "my sister".  The same is true for "A mother" etc.

That said, my kids do this all the time, but only as a joke. A kind of fake and ironic formality.

And it is perhaps worth noting that "Brother" is used formally by members of monastic colleges, and informally (mostly) in American English to refer to other men, who are not relatives.  The use of "Sister" as a *title* is restricted to nuns.  Don't say "Sister Sarah", unless you are referring to a member of a religious community. (Or historically a nurse, but this term is going out of use)

Comment: What about nurses?

Comment: A *lot* of people have been pushing for years to replace *[ward] **sisters*** in the NHS with gender-neutral ***charge nurses***